# How to make a question visible across stackexchange sites

Tags: support, feature-request, questions, popularity

If a question falls under two or more different stack exchange sites.

> Let's say we have two sites SE_A and SE_B and I have asked a question
>   in SE_A site (it is somewhat related to SE_B site). Assume that the
>   users who uses SE_A is low compared to SE_B.
>
> So to bring user attention and ultimately find a best answer for my
>   question, is there any way exist?

Edit: Now the number of SE clones made is increasing day by day, so now it is the good time to implement a way to handle this scenario.

Comment: You can make your question visible to the entire network by getting it on the hot questions list. But that requires a lot of upvotes and answers. :D:D:D

Comment: There are several sites that have very strong reactions when someone posts a question on multiple sites. The best option is to post on the most applicable site with a well crafted and interesting question.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes I agree. I imagine the process(questions appearing in hot list) should happen instant and if a question didn't find much response we have to back out(questions not appearing in hot list) automatically. I think way we can save considerable amount of waiting time. Eventually popular and more research oriented question Wins!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 7):

No, there is currently no way to do this. And you should not post exact duplicates of a question on different sites as that "[is considered abusive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012)".

Comment: Why can't the system automatically tell this to the user when he/she is posting a question across sites? Generally an end user may not have the proper knowledge about this. I understand it is complex as it requires the system to search all the related network sites to look for the questions. I still believe that this can be achieved in one way or another.